flutter How do I obfuscate the plug-in code that I want users of this plug-in to not see
flutter How do I obfuscate the plug-in code that I want users of this plug-in to not see
Now there's no way to do that

what do you mean by plug-in ?

you could check this link if you want to obfuscate your app https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

I hope to publish plug-ins, do not want others to see the source code, how should I deal with

you mean plugin to publish to pub.dev ??

Yes, is there a way to do that?

Of course you can't. All public packages on pub.dev must be human-readable. How else can we ensure that the code doesn't contain anything malicious?
